# Android camera code

Tags: android

I am trying to make an android application which uses camera. but somehow this code is not working. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Here is the code of my application.

aractivity.java
    package com.tanuj.myarapp;

```
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;  
import android.location.LocationManager;
 import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
 import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

public class Aractivity extends Activity {

SurfaceView cameraPreview;
SurfaceHolder previewHolder;
Camera camera;
boolean inPreview;
final static String TAG = "PAAR";
SensorManager sensorManager;
int orientationSensor;
int accelerometerSensor;
float headingAngle;
float pitchAngle;
float rollAngle;
float xAxis;
float yAxis;
float zAxis;
LocationManager locationManager;
double latitude;
double longitude;
double altitude;

    final SensorEventListener sensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION)
        {
        headingAngle = sensorEvent.values[0];
        pitchAngle = sensorEvent.values[1];
        rollAngle = sensorEvent.values[2];
        Log.d(TAG, "Heading: " + String.valueOf(headingAngle));
        Log.d(TAG, "Pitch: " + String.valueOf(pitchAngle));
        Log.d(TAG, "Roll: " + String.valueOf(rollAngle));
        }
        else if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
        {
        xAxis = sensorEvent.values[0];
        yAxis = sensorEvent.values[1];
        zAxis = sensorEvent.values[2];
        Log.d(TAG, "X Axis: " + String.valueOf(xAxis));
        Log.d(TAG, "Y Axis: " + String.valueOf(yAxis));
        Log.d(TAG, "Z Axis: " + String.valueOf(zAxis));
        }
        }
    public void onAccuracyChanged (Sensor senor, int accuracy) {
    //Not used
    }
    };
    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        altitude = location.getAltitude();
        Log.d(TAG, "Latitude: " + String.valueOf(latitude));
        Log.d(TAG, "Longitude: " + String.valueOf(longitude));
        Log.d(TAG, "Altitude: " + String.valueOf(altitude));
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        };
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_aractivity);
     inPreview = false;
    cameraPreview = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.cameraPreview);
    previewHolder = cameraPreview.getHolder();
    previewHolder.addCallback(surfaceCallback);
    previewHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    orientationSensor = Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION;
    accelerometerSensor = Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER;

        sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener,
                sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(orientationSensor),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener, sensorManager
                .getDefaultSensor(accelerometerSensor), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 2,
        locationListener);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_aractivity, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
super.onResume();
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000,
        2, locationListener);
sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener, sensorManager
        .getDefaultSensor(orientationSensor), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener, sensorManager
        .getDefaultSensor(accelerometerSensor), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
camera=Camera.open();
}
@Override
public void onPause() {
if (inPreview) {
camera.stopPreview();
}
locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
sensorManager.unregisterListener(sensorEventListener);

camera.release();
camera=null;
inPreview=false;
super.onPause();
}
SurfaceHolder.Callback surfaceCallback=new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
    camera.setPreviewDisplay(previewHolder);
    }
    catch (Throwable t) {
    Log.e("ProAndroidAR2Activity", "Exception i");
    }
    }
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int
            height) {
            Camera.Parameters parameters=camera.getParameters();
            Camera.Size size=getBestPreviewSize(width, height, parameters);
            if (size!=null) {
            parameters.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);
            camera.setParameters(parameters);
            camera.startPreview();
            inPreview=true;     
            }
    }
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        /*camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera=null;
        */
        }
};
private   Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(int width, int height,
        Camera.Parameters parameters) {
        Camera.Size result=null;
        for (Camera.Size size : parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes()) {
        if (size.width<=width && size.height<=height) {
        if (result==null) {
        result=size;
        }
        else {
        int resultArea=result.width*result.height;
        int newArea=size.width*size.height;
        if (newArea>resultArea) {
        result=size;
        }
        }
        }
        }
        return(result);
        }


           }
```

manifest file
        < manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         package="com.tanuj.myarapp"
         android:versionCode="1"
         android:versionName="1.0" 
        >

```
       <uses-sdk
       android:minSdkVersion="8"
       android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
       <activity
        android:name=".Aractivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_aractivity" 
        android:screenOrientation = "landscape"
        android:configChanges = "keyboardHidden|orientation"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

 </manifest>
```

activity_aractivity.xml(layout)

```
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     >

       <android.view.SurfaceView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/cameraPreview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        </android.view.SurfaceView>
    </RelativeLayout>


output of logcat
      '11-10 17:56:04.153: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(386): showStatusIcon on inactive         InputConnection
       11-10 17:56:16.732: D/er(386): in open()
       11-10 17:56:17.442: D/er(386): inOnresune'
```

Comment: Why is it not working? Could you provide any log output or exception stack trace?

Comment: i hve updated the above with logcat output..

Comment: Android website have very clean explanation of Android Camera. Here's the link - [Android Camera](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html).